# Cheapest Place to Get Windows Server Licenses for Hosting

Tags: hosting, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

So I have a hosting business and I tired of paying M$ an up front payment for Windows Server Web 2008, it screws up the cashflow something fierce. Is there a monthly service out there, I know SPLA is out there but I didn't see any monthly options. Aparently also M$ will not allow me to do Volume Licensing because I provide hosting to the public. Ideas?

Comment: You need to contact an MS Licensing vendor about this.

Comment: SPLA also offers 1 and 3 year options. Otherwise SPLA is ONLY about monthly payment, sorry. How could you miss that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closer at SPLA:

> Cash Flow Management: With SPLA, you
>   have minimal start-up costs, since you
>   only pay for licenses based on what
>   you make available to provide services
>   each month

Comment: THanks I wasn't totally sure how this worked, I will post results on pricing when i get them from the vendors.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm not understanding what it is you're "hosting" or you're misunderstanding the SPLA program. What is it exactly that you're "hosting".

http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/licensing/splabenefits.aspx

Comment: This is the way to go.  From the link above:  "Microsoft SPLA is the only Microsoft Volume Licensing program that allows Microsoft products to be used for commercial hosting."